# Remove Woocommerce product link

Tags: php, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

I'd like to remove the link from the Woocommerce product listings. I don't need the user to see the product detail pages, we are going to use Quick View instead. Anywho, I have been searching and everything I've found is outdated. This is the current `content-product.php` file: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-product.php and there are no anchor tags to simply remove.

I might need a hook but I'm not sure what to do. I tried a few but the link was still there. For example this didn't work when added to my functions.php:

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open','mbc_remove_link_on_thumbnail' );

 function mbc_remove_link_on_thumbnail($html){
      return strip_tags($html,'<img>');
 }
```

I also tried this which didn't work but I feel is close:

```
 remove_action ('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10);
 remove_action ('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5);
```

I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've done this was to take a copy of content-product.php and paste it into the root of your theme folder.

Comment out

`do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );`

and

`do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );`

Quick and dirty, but it worked for me.

Comment: Maybe I celebrated too soon. I lost the "Add to Cart" button this way. Did this happen to you?

Comment: Ah, I'm not using the add to cart button. My site is using a plugin for Request a Quote instead. I've just deactivated the plugin and yes my add to cart button is missing too. Back to the drawing board I'm afraid.

Answer (score 11):

A better & safer way to do this is by removing the open & close link actions. This will prevent side effects such as the add to cart button disappearing.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
```

You can add this code to your functions.php

Comment: And what do you do when that does not work? i honestly cant find where they add these links.... its hella annoying

Answer (score 0):

I found this.

```
/**
 * @snippet       Disable Link to Products @ Loop
 * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ http://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055
 * @sourcecode    http://businessbloomer.com/?p=19916
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 2.5.2
 */
// Close </a> tag just after it opens before product item

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title','bbloomer_close_permalink', 10 );
function bbloomer_close_permalink() {
?>
</a>
<?php
}

// Open <a> tag  just before it closes after product item

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','bbloomer_open_atag', 11);
function bbloomer_open_atag() {
?>
<a>
<?php
}

/**
 * Explanation for the hack!
 *
 * Before the loop item, a link opens...
 * After the loop item, a link closes...
 * We're basically adding a close and open so that
 * no content gets wrapped into <a>link</a>
 * 
 * Check wc-template-functions.php lines 545-556:
 *
 * function woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open() {
 *  echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">';
 * }
 *
 * function woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close() {
 *  echo '</a>';
 * }
 *
 */
```

Font Source:
http://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-disable-link-to-product-loop/

Comment: Please add an explanation as how it  answers the  question .. just dumping the code is not good.

Comment: You right.
First time in Stack.

I have tried alot of 'filter' , 'remove_action_', to remove this anchor.

The code i 'dumping' here, save my day.
You can get more information in font source:

http://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-disable-link-to-product-loop/

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be by a single line of code in your `functions.php` file.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' , 
'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open' , 10);
```

Put it into any function file. The link to the product will be gone.

Comment: Needs also `remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );` otherwise there will be a stray closing anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed it with jQuery like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('li.product a.woocommerce-loop-product__link').removeAttr('href');
});
</script>
```